# Stress-Strain behavior of ceramics at high temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, material-science, stress-strain

Can someone explain to me why do we observe the peak in the stress strain behavior at 1400 C and then a sudden decline followed by gradual increase? What does it signify? Does it have anything to do with localized pinning of the dislocations? and that initially stress required to free them is high but then once they are freed the stress reduces first and then eventually increases. I know ceramics don't exhibit work hardening but then how would one explain this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Hey there! Saw your Meta Stack Exchange "ordeal", glad to see you found the proper site. Cheers.

Comment: hahhahah thanks ! had to wait 40 mins for my blunder !!